# longlines mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I recently discovered longlines mode in Emacs (after having been a regular user for 5 yrs!). So I set in my .emacs file

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill) 
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'longlines-mode)
```

(do I still need auto-fill? I can't tell...) which also sets org-mode to operate in longlines-mode as well. This seems to mess up the table construction functionality so I'd like to disable longlines mode for org-mode (which appears to incorporate text-mode-hooks) but keep it enabled for text (.txt) files.

I wonder if anyone has a solution to this? I am slowly picking up bits of Emacs Lisp but have not studied up on manipulating mode-hooks yet...

Thanks much! -Stephen

Comment: I've been using emacs for about 5 years too and was recently exposed to super useful features from the answers at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367/the-single-most-useful-emacs-feature

Comment: Archived version of link: https://web.archive.org/web/20111127230153/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367/the-single-most-useful-emacs-feature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `visual-line-mode`, which supplants `longlines-mode` since Emacs-23.1.

Comment: Yes, I just switched to Emacs 23, so this works well - thank you.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. I wish they'd just nuke obsolete libraries like longlines-mode so that they're no longer accidentally available. :-)

Comment: Nice suggestion, I didn't know about visual-line-mode.  Note also that longlines-show-hard-newlines still works in visual line mode, which I find handy on occasion.  Re "nuking obsolete libraries" per the last comment, I'm more wondering why a new library was created instead of just upgrading longlines-mode.  Anyway simply removing a library without telling users about the replacement is not helpful.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Functionality is rarely removed from Emacs.  Unless it's in the way of new functionality old things are kept.  I find this policy rather nice.  You can pick up Emacs after 10 years of not using it and still get along nicely.  As for getting rid of longlines-mode specifically: visual-line-mode is somewhat different from longlines-mode in terms of functionality, the most significant difference being that longlines-mode wraps at fill-column whereas visual-line-mode wraps at the fringe.

Comment: longlines-mode is also much, much, much more performant than visual-line-mode when your lines are tens of thousands of characters long.

Comment: Following up, they have since deprecated and removed longlines-mode.  I am not happy with visual-line-mode as a replacement.  Wrapping at fill-column was so much nicer.  Now you need a MELPA package to get the old behavior back:
http://melpa.org/#/visual-fill-column

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to explicitly disable `longlines-mode` in `org-mode` by adding a hook to `org-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (longlines-mode -1)))
```

**Edit:** Thanks to [Török Gábor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73603/torok-gabor) for pointing out my elisp fail :-)

Comment: It should yes.  Basically it toggles `longlines-mode` until it returns `nil`, which means it is off.  I couldn't see another way to deterministically turn it off.

Comment: Why not use form `(longlines-mode -1)` as usual?

Answer (score 0):

I disable auto-fill mode when using longlines, and now that I'm aware of and using visual-line mode, that too.  I think it is unnecessary with either of these for my purposes, and would perhaps conflict with them (inserting hard new lines at the same or different places where longlines/visual line would insert soft newlines).